# Parseo de fecha y hora

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Estoy haciendo un script para analizar unas trazas, y necesitaría *parsear* la fecha/hora de las mismas, que está en una cadena así:

```
2021-07-24 14:29:10.657
```

Siempre tienen exactamente ese formato, con el mismo tamaño de campo.

Lo estoy haciendo así, pero me parece demasiado complicado; seguro que hay al menos otra forma de hacerlo, con menos código:

```
import datetime

TestLine = '[2021-07-24 14:29:10.657][nombremodu] Un mensaje de log cualquiera'

def parseTimestamp( line ):
    dy = int( line[1:5] )
    dm = int( line[6:8] )
    dd = int( line[9:11] )
    hh = int( line[12:14] )
    hm = int( line[15:17] )
    hs = int( line[18:20] )
    millis = int( line[21:24] )

    return datetime.datetime( dy, dm, dd, hh, hm, hs, millis * 1000 ), line[38:]

test = parseTimestamp( TestLine )
print( TestLine, test[0], test[1] )
```